# The category of small presheaves is locally small

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory

Let $C$ be a locally small category, so the objects form a class (in the sense of [NBG set theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)) and the maps between two objects form a set.

Now, it is well known that the presheaves does not form a (locally small) category anymore: the maps between two objects does not form a set, and even the objects does not form a class anymore.

Instead, one can consider the [small presheaves](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+presheaf), which it is known to be a locally small category: the homorphisms between to small presheaves form a set clearly.

But, how it is proved that the objects form a class?

I understand that the "collection" of objects is some sort of colimit of classes, indexed on a class. But what sort of axiom one uses in order to know one gets a class?

Comment: How can it be something other than a class?

Comment: @fosco Imagine that the objects of the category are any subclass of your given (proper) class. Then they do not form a class. This is what could happen if you consider all the presheaves (not the small ones).

Comment: The claim is not literally true. You have to use proxies for the objects and morphisms in order to get a locally small category in the precise technical sense you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that (in NBG) the elements of any class are sets.
In particular, it is impossible to have any class of presheaves when every presheaf itself is a proper class.
Similarly, it is impossible to have any class of presheaf morphisms when every presheaf morphism itself is a proper class.
The trick is to use proxies for the objects and morphisms – which implicitly means replacing the purported category with an equivalent one.

For the objects, instead of small presheaves, we take pairs $(\mathcal{I}, X)$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is a small category and $X$ is a diagram $\mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$.
(For the purpose of this exercise, the domain and codomain are not considered part of the data of a diagram; so $X$ is just an ordered pair whose first component is a set of ordered pairs consisting of an object of $\mathcal{I}$ and an object of $\mathcal{C}$ and whose second component is etc.)
We define morphisms $(\mathcal{I}, X) \to (\mathcal{J}, Y)$ to be elements of the following set:
$$\textstyle \varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}^\textrm{op}} \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} \mathcal{C} (X, Y)$$
Concretely, that means that a morphism $f : (\mathcal{I}, X) \to (\mathcal{J}, Y)$ consists of, for each object $i$ in $\mathcal{I}$, an object $j_i$ in $\mathcal{J}$ and a morphism $f_i : X (i) \to Y (j_i)$ in $\mathcal{C}$, such that certain equations induced by the diagram $X : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$ are satisfied modulo certain equivalence relations induced by the diagram $Y : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$.
Composition is defined in the obvious way (but checking that it is well defined is tedious).

It is clear by construction that the above is a locally small category... but is it equivalent to the intuitive category of small presheaves?
Well, a small presheaf is a small colimit of representables, say $\varinjlim_\mathcal{I} h_X$.
Given $\varinjlim_\mathcal{I} h_X$ and $\varinjlim_\mathcal{J} h_Y$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\textstyle \textrm{Hom} \left( \varinjlim_\mathcal{I} h_X, \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} h_Y \right) &
\textstyle \cong \varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}^\textrm{op}} \textrm{Hom} \left(  h_X, \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} h_Y \right) \\
& \textstyle \cong \varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}^\textrm{op}} \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} h_Y (X) \\
& \textstyle = \varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}^\textrm{op}} \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} \mathcal{C} (X, Y)
\end{aligned}$$
by the Yoneda lemma.
It is then clear that we have a fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects functor from the locally small category defined above to the intuitive category of small presheaves.